# How to search in Java inside a JSON object for specific key during JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing, search, iterator

I am parsing the following JSON file http://pastebin.com/Mb5E6Ewf using json-simple library in the Java class with name `JacksonStreamExample`.

In this JSON file I have a JSON object and inside it an array of 6 JSON objects with the following structure:

```
{"cells": [{object with name START},{object with name END},{object with name ACTIVITY 1},{object with name ACTIVITY 2},{object with name link},{object with name link}]}
```

I want to search inside these 6 JSON objects for `wi_name:START` and get `wi_displayName` of this specific JSON object, but so far in my code I only get all `wi_name` keys of these 6 JSON objects in an iterator. Can you tell me how to fix my code please?

This is the code of my Java class:

```
package jsontoxml;

import java.io.*;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.*;
import java.util.*;


public class JacksonStreamExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("text.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray cells = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cells");
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = cells.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){

           System.out.println(iterator.next().get("wi_name"));

        }

     } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

     }

  }

}
```

and the output is the following:

```
START
END
ACTIVITY_1
ACTIVITY_2
null
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing my code this way:

```
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
        if(jsonObject2.get("wi_name").equals("START")){
                System.out.println(jsonObject2.get("wi_displayName"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Traversing JSON using org.json API is usually a bit messy since it lacks quite all comfort-features but here you go:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  JSONobject current = iterator.next();
  if(current.get("wi_name") != null && current.get("wi_name").equals("START")) {
     // maybe do some null- and/or empty-checks here or what ever you want with the data
     System.out.println(current.get("wi_displayName"));                
  };
}
```

Hope this helps!